# Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'. Flutter M1 Chip

Tags: flutter

I can't run my project in flutter on my Macbook air m1 chip device, I tried many methods but I couldn't find a solution.

[the error comes out like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJMRm.png)

[when i try to run the app it stays like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZZ2C.png)

EDİT------>

```
Solved like this
1) run -> cd iOS
2) run -> pod deintegrate
3) run -> pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pod issue.You can follow this step.

1. sudo gem update cocoapods --pre
2. pod update
3. clean
4. build

Comment: thank you                                                                                                             Solved like this
1) run -> cd iOS
2) run -> pod deintegrate
3) run -> pod install